# Having trouple with Pip

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

I'm trying to install pip in Windows and after trying [[How do I install pip on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750806/how-do-i-install-pip-on-windows/12476379#12476379][1]) and after executing       `get-pip.py`    pip is still not recognized in the cmd, what could be the problem?  Trying to run it again will only display the message:       `Requirement already up to date: pip in c:\users...\lib\site-packages`  I'm new to Python and I don't know if there is any other way to install pip

(BTW this is my first post, sorry if I´m doing a mistake here)

Comment: Yes, that was the solution i´ve tryed and yet no folder was created, neither the "pip" command is recognized on the cmd

Comment: according to one of the comments in that answer "to start the "build in" pip you have to use python -m pip on windows!"  I would read all the responses a bit more thoroughly there.

Comment: I have already tryed that too, it does not simply works, in general python instructions do not work and i have already set the path variable

Comment: @phd also has a good suggestion there.

Comment: @phd thank you i found the problem, i fixed it desintalling python and installing everything again, thank you for the help